# Dot instead of bibentry

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm having some trouble with BibTeX, in particular with this bib entry:

```
@Proceedings{un9,
title = {\donothing{i}}{Disarmament, demobilization and reintegration - Report of the Secretary-General},
year = {2006},
address = {New York},
organization = {UNGA [United Nations General Assembly]},
note = {U.N. Doc. A/60/705},
}
```

In .bbl file, it becomes:

```
\bibitem{un9}
{\em \donothing{i}}.
```

and I got only a dot in the final printing.
That's the code I'm using, any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\providecommand*{\donothing}[1]{}

\frenchspacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{url}
\urldef\myurl\url{http://www.peacekeepingbestpractices.unlb.org/Pbps/library/Handbook%20on%20UN%20PKOs.pdf}
\urldef\urlhazen\url{http://www.un.org/esa/socdev/sib/egm/paper/Jennifer%20Hazen.pdf}
\urldef\berlinplusurl\url{http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cmsUpload/03-11-11%20Berlin%20Plus%20press%20note%20BL.pdf}
\urldef\urlecps\url{http://unrol.org/doc.aspx?d=2117}

\newcommand{\citation}[1]{``#1''}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\subsection*{UN documents}}
\bibliography{un}
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is `{\donothing{i}}` at the front of the title field in your bib entry? Normally, that would be the title of the entry. I'd guess that the BibTeX parser sees a valid group there and ignores the rest of the field.

Comment: I'm using `donothing` command to order manually all entries, but the error occurs only in that case!

Comment: Can you put the command inside the braces containing the actual title `title = {\donothing{i} Disarmament, ...`? Better still, what sort order are you going for: in order of citation, by author, title, totally arbitrary, etc?

Comment: I'm going for an author-year order, but many entries are `proceedings` (no `author` field), so it printed by title order. That's why I'm using `donothing`!

Comment: Try using only one set of outer braces. If that doesn't work, someone else will likely have a better idea.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't compile correctly (wrong command error).

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 2):

This is the log when running BibTeX:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: un9.aux
The style file: siam.bst
Database file #1: un9.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 2 of file un9.bib
 : title = {\donothing{i}}
 :                        {Disarmament, demobilization and reintegration - Report of the Secretary-General},
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--to sort, need editor, organization, or key in un9
Warning--empty year in un9
(There was 1 error message)
```

which clearly shows the issue: you have a wrong brace after `\donothing{i}`. The entry should be

```
@Proceedings{un9,
title = {\donothing{i}{Disarmament, demobilization and reintegration - Report of the Secretary-General}},
year = {2006},
address = {New York},
organization = {UNGA [United Nations General Assembly]},
note = {U.N. Doc. A/60/705},
}
```

Remove ``` \newcommand\citation[1]{``#1''} ``` which is completely wrong.